# When downloading file in ASP.Net Core, my file is returned from server correctly, but does not save from UI

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-core, razor

I have a datagrid on my UI, which allows the user to select from a list of files. Upon selection, a download button appears, which when pressed, passes the file id to my controller via Ajax, which then gets the file and returns it to the frontend using File(fileStream, contentType, fileDownloadName).

My only problem is that it does not save in the browser. Upon debugging and inspecting in the browser, the server is sending the correct response, so I'm stuck. Any help much appreciated.

Also, when I enter the whole URL with ID parameter in the browser it downloads successfully, eg: https://localhost:44346/home/Download/?loadId=38.

Here is the relevant code:

// HTML with datagrid and download button

```
        <div data-options="dxItem: { title: 'Load History', icon: 'find' } ">
            <div id="gridContainer2"></div>
            <div id="downloadButton"></div>
        </div>
```

// Controller with logic for getting file by Id and returning it:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Download(int loadId)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Attempting to download Load ID: " + loadId + " from UI");

        var outputFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\wwwroot\\output\\";
        var name = GetFileName(loadId, outputFolder);
        var path = Path.Combine(outputFolder, name);

        var memory = new MemoryStream();

        if (loadId > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
                }

                memory.Position = 0;    
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error($"Unable to copy load {loadId} to memory for download: " + e);
            }

            Log.Info($"Results for file load: " + loadId + " download triggered successfully");

            return File(memory, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                "Downloaded.xlsx");
        }

        else
        {
            return new EmptyResult();
        }

    }


    public string GetFileName(int loadId, string outputFolder)
    {

        Log.Info($"Locating results for load {loadId} on web server");

        var resultsName = @"Results_Load_" + loadId + "_*";
        var results = "";
        var d = new DirectoryInfo(outputFolder);

        try
        {
            foreach (var file in d.GetFiles(resultsName))
            {
                Log.Info($"Results for load {loadId} located for download");
                results = file.Name;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error($"Results for load {loadId} not found on server: " + e);
            return null; 
        }

        return results; 

    }
```

//EDIT: Jquery added:

//JQuery datagrid on my view, which calls the getLoadId method when user selects data row:

```
    $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: DevExpress.data.AspNet.createStore({
            loadUrl: url + "/GetLoadHistory",
            key: "loadId"

        }),
        selection: {
            mode: "single"
        },
        hoverStateEnabled: true,
        paging: {
            pageSize: 10
        },

        editing: {
            mode: 'row',

        },
        onSelectionChanged: getLoadId
    });
```

//JQuery functions with Ajax which passes selected loadId to controller:

```
function getLoadId() {
    var dataGrid = $("#gridContainer2").dxDataGrid("instance");
    var loadIds = dataGrid.getSelectedRowKeys();
    var loadId = loadIds[0];

    if (loadId > 0)
    {
        console.log("Load ID: " + loadId);
        download(loadId);

    }
}

function download(loadId) {
    $("#downloadButton").dxButton({
        text: "Download Selected",
        type: "default",
        icon: "/favicon.ico",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        useSubmitBehavior: true,
        onClick: function(e) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://localhost:44346/home/Download/',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    loadId: loadId
                }
            }).done(function() {
                DevExpress.ui.notify("Downloading results for Load ID: " + loadId, "info", 1500);
            });
        }
    });

    console.log("Load ID: " + loadId + " download processed");

};
```

Comment: We have to see your javascript. If you're calling the controller from javascript using ajax, you have to handle the response yourself.

Comment: Cheers, now added

Answer (score 1):

When using Ajax, the browser does not automatically do *anything* with the response. It does not automatically offer to download a file, in the same way it does not automatically play a video or show an image.

You have to tell the browser what to do.

You can either

- redirect the user to the download URL, instead of using Ajax. This is simplest. Try it out!
- Create a "url object" when you get the response, and use it to start the "download process" in the browser. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970672) for an example.

There are also various older hacks using iframes and the like, but I would avoid them these days.